# jQuery Ajax Response: getting response as null on success

Tags: ajax, jquery

I wanted to invoke a .net webservice which is hosted locally on my machine from jQuery .ajax().
the script is included in the static .html file.
the success function is triggered but the response data is NULL.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: '{continent: "' + $('#txtContinent').val() + '"}',
            url: "http://localhost:60931/Service1.asmx/GetCountries",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {

            alert(response);

            },
            failure: function(msg) {

                $('#result').empty().append(msg);
            }
        });
```

When i alert the response its giving me NULL,
can anyone tell me where im goin wrong, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Firebug installed, or (if you're using Chrome) have you looked at the console in the Developer Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you might be calling the ajax from a static page which is not in `http://localhost:60931/`. You can put the static html in the localhost and try to run it via the same url. Or you can debug your ajax call by adding

```
error : function(xhr,status,error){
    alert(status);
},
```